# Pixelpadding between bars?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I was wondering if its possible to decide pixels between two bars? I got 2 series that represents some numbers, and they are standing side by side, 2 and 2 bars next to each other. I just want to control the space between the bars that stands next to each other. For example 10 px.

I've tried different settings from highcharts but havent found anything that seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `pointPadding: 0` and in `load` event position the columns in the way you want:

```
chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var series = this.series;

            series[0].points.forEach(function(p, i) {
                p.graphic.attr({
                    translateX: 5
                });
                series[1].points[i].graphic.attr({
                    translateX: -5
                });
            });
        }
    }
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointPadding: 0
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/13re4Lok/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parameters whick can help you `pointWidth` and `pointPadding`

[pointWidth Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.pointWidth)

[pointPadding Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.pointPadding)

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    pointPadding: 0.3,
    pointWidth: 10 // Will ignore pointPadding if used
  }
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/4fnLjgyk/)